# Invoke a function on a ruby module

Tags: ruby, rspec

Here's my folder structure:

```
root
  - app
    - helpers
      - application_helper.rb
  - test
    - helpers
      - application_helper_test.rb
```

Here's what application_helper.rb looks like:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def replace_links_with_urls(text)
    text.gsub(%r{<a[^>]*? href=['"]([^'"]*)?['"].*?>(.*?)</a>}m, "\\2 ( \\1 )")
  end
end
```

Here's what application_helper_test.rb looks like:

```
   require File.expand_path("../../../app/helpers/application_helper", __FILE__)
    describe ApplicationHelper do
      describe "#replace_links_with_urls" do
        it "does not replace non-links" do
          ApplicationHelper::replace_links_with_urls("ABC <b>bold</b>").should == "ABC <b>bold</b>"
        end
      end
  end
```

The error I get is:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `replace_links_with_urls' for ApplicationHelper:Module
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your function using self, like this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def self.replace_links_with_urls(text)
    text.gsub(%r{<a[^>]*? href=['"]([^'"]*)?['"].*?>(.*?)</a>}m, "\\2 ( \\1 )")
  end
end
```

Then you can call it using:

```
ApplicationHelper.replace_links_with_urls("asd")
```

Or declare it without using self, include the module using

```
include ApplicationHelper
```

And call the function

So your test will be:

```
require File.expand_path("../../../app/helpers/application_helper", __FILE__)
include ApplicationHelper
describe ApplicationHelper do
    describe "#replace_links_with_urls" do
        it "does not replace non-links" do
            ApplicationHelper::replace_links_with_urls("ABC <b>bold</b>").should == "ABC <b>bold</b>"
        end
    end
end
```

Also, check that the code you posted the replace_links_with_urls function has two def, don't know if you have that same typo in your code or just here.

Comment: How could I change the test and not the ApplicationHelper module to just `include ApplicationHelper`

Comment: Yes, you're right. You can do that as well without using self. Also check that in your question the replace_links_with_urls has two def

Comment: That was it! Thanks. I had to both require and include it.